# MVC index view shows dropdown ID instead of name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I'm working on getting some basic dropdown boxes working and right now the only problem I'm having is that the index view of TTTime shows the Id of the selected value instead of the string "proj_code" for that value.  I've automatically generated the controller and views from my model and then edited those to give the proj_code field a dropdown.  Here are the relevant parts of the code and just ask if there's anything else I could provide that would help.

TTTime Controller code for the dropdown:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        TTTime tttime = db.TTTime.Find(id);
        if (tttime == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var query = from c in db.TTSites select c;
        ViewBag.proj_code = new SelectList(query, "ID", "client_id", tttime.proj_code);
        return View(tttime);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Time/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        TTTime tttime = new TTTime();
        tttime.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        var query = from c in db.TTSites select c;
        ViewBag.proj_code = new SelectList(query, "ID", "client_id");
        return View(tttime);
    }
```

Create/Edit/Delete view code for cust_id:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.proj_code)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("proj_code", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.proj_code)
    </div>
```

Index view code that just gives the id value but should show the proj_code string:

```
    @model IEnumerable<TimeTracker.Models.TTTime>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employee)
    </th>
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.hrs_calc)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cust_id)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.proj_code)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.type)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employee)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hrs_calc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cust_id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.proj_code)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Could you also post your Index action code?

Comment: I've added the full index code

Answer (score 0):

The only dropdown I see in your code is on your create/edit/delete page but where I normally put my list you have string.empty

```
@Html.DropDownList("proj_code", ViewBag.proj_code, "Select One")
```

ViewBag may not be the best option for passing the data.  You might try passing the list through the model or calling a static method in the drop down instead.  Hopefully this helps.